# Having issue in plugin wordpress? Tried with different plugin no improvement

Tags: wordpress, plugins

```
How to add a separate banner image for every different post on Wordpress? 
the plugin used so far : but no improvement .Did any one tell me what to do now?
```

1. Unique Headers Plugin
2. WP Display Header.
3. WP Header Images

Here is the link: https://surabigroups.com/

```
for example: 
1. I want to add a separate banner for this post [https://surabigroups.com/hr-activites/][2] 
2. I want to add a different banner for this post [https://surabigroups.com/hr-conference-meet/][2] like this I want to add a different different banner for a different post
```

Plugin user so far :
1. Unique Headers Plugin 
2. WP Display Header.
3. WP Header Images

Answer (score 0):

I do not know actually what do you mean, but every post has a **featured image** in wordpress which you can use as a background image (just you need to add inline css) or you can use a **custom field** (by downloading the custom field plugin) to add image for background image for every post.

Comment: I don't want backgroud image, i just want to add different banner image for every post. custom field is for form fields, once again look my post : https://surabigroups.com/hr-activites/, https://surabigroups.com/hr-conference-meet/  i am have same banner for different post, How to add different banner

Comment: i have added Featured image, but this comes after my banner, have a look https://surabigroups.com/hr-conference-meet/ , how to find that div to add line css

Comment: can any one help,me please, banner image i want different one for different post

Comment: any one please?